# Images are moving each other on Zooming effect

Tags: css

Images on my website pushing each other when I go over them with my cursor. I just want them to get big not to push the text after them or other images.

CSS Code:

```
#pdesign {margin:0;padding:0;width:670px;font-size:18px;}
#pdesign tr td {text-align:center;margin:0;padding:20px
0;float:left;width:223px;height:300px;}
```

Link: http://tinyurl.com/82ku7wf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that by using table ;)